# Fixing broken zip file by using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, zip, corrupt

When i execute "zip -FF /Users/myZip.zip? --out Users/myFixed.zip" in my Mac terminal,the broken zip file is fixed.
When i try to fix the same broken zip file as below it gives me the following error.

Please share your opinions to fix this issue.

### The Code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "zip -FF/Users/myZip.zip 
   --out /Users/myFixed.zip");
   pb1.redirectErrorStream(true);
   Process p =pb1.start();
```

---

### The Error Message:

```
1 Fix archive (-FF) - salvage what can
2   zip warning: could not open input archive: /Users/myZip.zip
3 Scanning for entries... 
4  Could not find: /Users/myZip.z01
5
6 
7 Hit c      (change path to where this split file is)
8     s      (skip this split)
9     q      (abort archive - quit)
10    e      (end this archive - no more splits)
11    z      (look for .zip split - the last split)
```

---

Comment: `zip warning: could not open input archive: /Users/myZip.zip` - I would imagine that the file is actually below `/Users/<username>/`

Comment: No matter where i put the **(/Users/<username>/ or /Users/<username>/Desktop/)** broken file , i can only fix the broken file in mac terminal by the  `zip -FF broken.zip --out fixed.zip` command but it doesnt work in my program @ScaryWombat

Comment: see below answer

Answer (score 0):

Each argument should be a different String

e.g.

```
ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "zip", "-FF", "/Users/myZip.zip", 
   "--out", "/Users/myFixed.zip");
```

Comment: I tried but i got the same result.Even try with the apache commons exec                    `String line = "bash -c  zip -FF /Users/<username>/myZip.zip --out /Users/<username>/myFixed.zip";
  CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(line);
  System.out.println(cmdLine.toString());
         Executor executer = new DefaultExecutor();
         executer.execute(cmdLine);
                executer.setExitValue(1);`        But  still the same error!@ScaryWombat